# How to catch TransientPropertyValueException

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I am using spring data jpa to save entities in the database. I am getting TransientPropertyValueException which is because I am trying to save a product which has an associated brand which is not saved. I want to catch TransientPropertyValueException which seems to be impossible. I know I can solve this problem by using CascadeType. But I do not want to use that. Instead I want to catch the exception and rethrow CustomException with a message.
How can I catch this exception. Any comment is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

I tried this as well

```
if(exception.getCause() instanceof TransientPropertyValueException)
```

but this does not work.

Entity Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Product")
public class Product implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "PRODUCT_SEQ")
@SequenceGenerator(name="PRODUCT_SEQ", sequenceName = "PRODUCT_SEQ", allocationSize=1)
@Column(name = "PRODUCT_ID", nullable = false)
private long productId;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "BRAND_ID", nullable = false)
private Brand brandId;
```

This is how I intend to catch it.

```
catch(Exception e) {
if (exception.getCause() instanceof ConstraintViolationException)
            throw new CustomException("...");
// catch TransientPropertyValueException
if (exception.getCause() instanceof TransientPropertyValueException)
            throw new CustomException("...");
}
```

Comment: Post the code sample of how do you catch that exception

Comment: Posted the sample in the question itself. @NikolayShevchenko

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.exception.ExceptionUtils;
...
int index = ExceptionUtils.indexOfThrowable(exception, TransientPropertyValueException.class);
if (index > 0) {
   //here we are
}
...
```

One more method
org.apache.commons.lang3.exception.ExceptionUtils.hasCause

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.9/org/apache/commons/lang3/exception/ExceptionUtils.html#hasCause-java.lang.Throwable-java.lang.Class-